# How to download file from jenkins artifact using wget where file name version will be changing

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, wget

Using below code i am able to download **srww_1.2.3.4.dmg** file but file version number will change daily so i cannot hardcode filename.

How to download file without hardcoding file name.

```
wget "https://test.com/job/testreport/job/${{parameters.test_buildjob}}/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/directrs/srww_1.2.3.4.dmg" --no-check-certificate --http-user=$(USERNAME) --http-password=$(PASSWORD) --auth-no-challenge --no-verbose -O srww_1.2.3.4.dmg
```

Please help me.

Comment: Tried to store the daily version number into a certain file and read it before calling wget?

Comment: @LittleSanti is it possible to do by passing partial file name some thing like that. I don't want to create any files so.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the ReST API of Jenkins:

`https://test.com/job/testreport/job/${{parameters.test_buildjob}}/lastSuccessfulBuild/api`

Particularly, the XML or JSON form should provide you with the version number built by the job, so you can get the version number first, and then use it when calling to wget.

Comment: yes i am able to download but if i get help just by passing partial file name will be able to download?

Comment: No. My suggestion consists on getting the exact version number you need to form the exact, full file name.